# ffmpeg won't write incoming video stream to files until the stream is terminated

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, rtsp, rtp

#### The Problem:

Using ffmpeg from the command line, my* main goal is to read an incoming *continuous* (UDP/RTP) stream and simultaneously output the data to a `.ts` file, via ffmpeg.  The issue is that ffmpeg won't write anything to a file until the incoming stream is terminated.

#### More Details:

I am currently receiving an h.264/mp4 file over an RTP stream and am trying to convert that stream to HLS as the data is received. However, ffmpeg wont start writing the HLS playlist files until the stream is done transmitting. The data is live footage from an RTSP camera so theoretically the data stream will never end, thus I am stopping it manually.  Once I stop sending the data from the camera and ffmpeg notices the stream has ended, it will start writing the output file. Is there a way to write the file **as it is being read?** I am not doing any encoding, just splitting the data into an HLS TS playlist.

Here's the command I'm currently using:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,crypto,udp,rtp -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 -v 9 -loglevel 99 -i a.sdp -c copy -an -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type event stream.m3u8
```

Also I am not using the RTSP input option on ffmpeg because I need to tell ffmpeg to listen on a specific port rather than automatically choosing a port to listen on for the response data.  I couldn't find a way to specify the serverside port while also specifying an RTSP URL as the input.  If there's a way to do that, please let me know.

Any other suggestions also welcome.

**TL;DR:** How do I read an incoming video stream and simultaneously output a new file, via ffmpeg.

** This question is actually my coworker's*

Comment: I have the same issue with a SDP file as input. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the option that you are looking for?

> `temp_file`
>
> Write segment data to filename.tmp and rename to filename only once the segment is complete. A webserver serving up segments can be configured to reject requests to *.tmp to prevent access to in-progress segments before they have been added to the m3u8 playlist. This flag also affects how m3u8 playlist files are created. If this flag is set, all playlist files will written into temporary file and renamed after they are complete, similarly as segments are handled. But playlists with file protocol and with type (hls_playlist_type) other than vod are always written into temporary file regardless of this flag. Master playlist files (master_pl_name), if any, with file protocol, are always written into temporary file regardless of this flag if master_pl_publish_rate value is other than zero.

Quoted from the [docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually the issue is that it won't create any file whether it is a tmp or a .ts file until it sees that it isn't receiving any more RTP packets. My goal is for it to read and write at the same time.